# Instantiating a JavaScript Constructor function from Typescript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing in Angular/Typescript and importing an external javascript library.  Having some troubles instantiating an object in the library that is a constructor function.

The javascript function is...

```
var amf = { some declarations etc }

amf.Client = function(destination, endpoint, timeout) {

};
```

The import declaration in Typescript...

```
import * as amf from '../../src/amf.js';
```

The code calling the object...

```
const amfClient = new amf.Client('param1','param2', param3);
```

The error in chome im getting...

```
ERROR TypeError: _src_amf_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Client is not a constructor
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Try logging `console.log(amf)` to inspect what your object looks like. Depending on how it's exported, imported, and how your `tsconfig` is set to work with modules, it could be that you need to access it as `amf.amf.Client()`, `amf()` or even `amf.default()`.

Comment: Well, `amf.Client = function(...)` That's a simple function, not a Class. So it should just be called with `const amfClient = amf.Client('param1','param2', param3)` without `new`, I guess

Comment: Thanks for the responses... it see's the client function and when i take out the new it gives me a "Client is not a function" error.  Interesting note...if i do this javascript tags in html... <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var amfClient = new amf.Client('param1','param2', param3);   it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript wasn't going to instantiate this class unless i gave it a type def file.  So I had to create a amf.d.ts file put it in a types folder and make the reference in the tsconfig.json file so the compiler would recognize the types in the javascript library.

"compilerOptions": {
....
 "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
}